# How can I hide some elements of Build and Run (dirty project and solution)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, resharper

[image: Shows a screenshot of my solution on Visual Studio]

I'm using Resharper Build and it opens a new window with run and debug button. I don't know what are these green rectangles but I know that ins't helpful to me. What are these 2 rectangles and how can I hide it? I just use the run and debug button